# Gauss Divergence Theorem finding limits

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Use Gauss Divergence Theorem to comput $$\int \int \limits_S F\cdot n dS$$ where $n$ is the outward normal for the following:

$S$ is the surface of the unit sphere $\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$, $n$ is the outward normal and $$F(x,y,z)=(xz-z^2,-yz,z+x+y)$$

So if the $div(F)=1$ but what is $V$?

If I make $V=\{x,y \in [0,1], z \in [-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2},\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}]\}$, would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V is the whole volume of the ball. Since your divergence is $1$, the integral is just the volume of the unit ball, which is $\frac{4}{3}\pi$.

Using integration, it is

$$\int^1_{-1}\int^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}_{-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}dzdydx$$

You might have to use trig substitution to calculate it.

Or you can use spherical coordinate,

$$\int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^1_0 r^2\sin{\phi}dr d\theta d\phi$$

which is much easier to calculate.

Comment: can you show me the way to do it that actually uses integration?

Comment: I am not sure why you want to do it using integration, since apparently the volume way is much easier. But I will edit it in the answer.

Comment: would you be able to explain how you got those limits for the integration please

Comment: To get the $z$ limits, you consider the ball as upper half and lower half. $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ for the upper half, $z=-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ for the lower half. Now mapping the ball to the xy-plane, you have a disk. The disk also consists of upper half and lower half, in terms of x-value, they are $\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$. The boundary of x-values of a unit disk are $\pm 1$. I am sure you can find the standard explanation of spherical coordinate in your textbook.